# Clearing controllers in Rails 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I made a Wysiwyg module where a user can create custom text areas for different sections of their website.

I do this by checking in the controllers if they have created one for this particular section yet. If they have, it redirects them :

```
def new
  if Wysiwyg.find_by_name(params[:name]) != nil
    redirect_to edit_admin_wysiwyg_path(Wysiwyg.find_by_name(params[:name]))
  else
    @wysiwyg = Wysiwyg.new(:name => params[:name])
  end
end
```

The trouble is is Rails still believes its a 'new' even though I have redirected the user to edit. How can I 'clear' the controller's and make it really sincerely believe it is actually an 'edit' ?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying the the form that is rendered for your #edit action has a route going to #create instead of #update?

Comment: Yes! Strange as it is because my params says its in edit, my site is `/wysiwygs/1/edit` , but when I click submit, it goes straight to a create. My form instantiates as : `<% form_for(@wysiwyg, :url => admin_wysiwygs_path, :html => { :method => :post}) do |f| %>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah my problem was in my form instantiation

Old and Evil:

```
<% form_for(@wysiwyg, :url => admin_wysiwygs_path, :html => { :method => :post}) do |f| %>
```

Correct:

```
<% form_for @wysiwyg, :url => admin_wysiwyg_path do |f| %>
```